# Cron Jobs lag my website while they run

Tags: php, mysql, cron

For my website I have Cron Jobs running every 30 minutes and if I try to access my website at these 30 minute marks I either get a 500 Internal Server Error or I get a 5-10 second loading time for any page on the site.

I'm using Php and my cron jobs are using Php and MySQL.

How do I make it so it either doesn't lag my whole website or make it quicker so the lag is less?

Crons: [image]

One of the crons that run every 15 mins:

```
<?php
require('functions.php');

global $mysqli;

$select = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `tkn` FROM `users` ORDER BY `dt` ASC LIMIT 0, 200");
$select->execute();
$select->bind_result($cur_token);

$tokens = array();

while($select->fetch())
{
    array_push($tokens, $cur_token);
}

foreach($tokens as $token)
{
    $api = Class::Instance($token);
    $info = $api->Users->Info();

    if(empty($info->error))
    {
        $info->data->token = $token;
        updateUser($info->data);

    } else if($info->error->code == 400) {
        $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 0 WHERE `tkn` = ?");
        $update->bind_param('s', $token);
        $update->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

Other Cron Job:

```
<?php
require('functions.php');

global $mysqli;

$select = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `email`, `username`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` IS NOT NULL AND `email` <> '' AND `credits` < `credits_offered` AND `emailed_credits` = 0");
$select->execute();
$select->bind_result($email, $username, $id);

$users = array();

while($select->fetch())
{
    $users[] = array("id" => $id, "email" => $email, "username" => $username);
}

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $to      = $user['email'];
    $subject = '';
    $message = "";
    $headers = 'From: email@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: reply@domain.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `emailed` = 1 WHERE `id` = ?");
    $update->bind_param('i', &$user['id']);

    $update->execute();
    $update->close();
}


?>
```

### How can I make these lag less or not lag at all?

Comment: Do you really expect any useful answer to this without any further information?

Comment: It might help if you said what the cronjobs do....

Comment: What are the cron job(s) doing? How long do they run? Do they do any http requests on your site using sessions? Do the jobs lock any resources the rest of the site requires? Your question is unanswerable without more detail

Comment: as above, please edit your cron list and contents of those scripts you suspect are lagging

Comment: 1 of my crons mass emails user who has a specific criteria. Other one does HTTP requests for 50 users in my db and updates fields with the result of the requests.

Comment: Cron Job**s** - how many? Please add your crontab to the question and if it calls scripts, also these scripts. Also you can do some metrics and log load and i/o in that time so it would be actually more visible what's stressing your server at these peaks. `$ vmstat 1` - And as you have more than one, do not start both at once if you already know they are slow. Instead of all 50 users at once, do two users per minute, than you can do 60 users in 30 minutes.

Comment: Check your processlist to see what's slow and then ask for help.

Comment: Hi, updated post with more info.

@MarcB

Comment: Add a lockfile to your cronjobs, such that no more than one instance of them is running.

Comment: My crons will never run more than once at a time @wildplasser

Comment: How do you know? They might be held by a database lock. Or even by other activity.

Comment: @xception please review post. They don't take longer than 20 seconds. I would know because I made it, thank you.

Comment: It might be the query (heavy) or the API call or many other things, you should use a profiler to locate the bottle-neck and handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first suggestion would be to move the prepare calls out of the loops. Updates will lock your tables for a while so only update after finishing the operation ... cache what needs updating in an array and start a transaction, do all updates than commit.
updated code sample for the mailing script

```
<?php
require('functions.php');

global $mysqli;

$select = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `email`, `username`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `email` IS NOT NULL AND `email` <> '' AND `credits` < `credits_offered` AND `emailed_credits` = 0");
$select->execute();
$select->bind_result($email, $username, $id);

$users = array();

while($select->fetch())
{
    $users[] = array("id" => $id, "email" => $email, "username" => $username);
}

$u = array();

foreach($users as $user)
{
    $to      = $user['email'];
    $subject = '';
    $message = "";
    $headers = 'From: email@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: reply@domain.com';

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    $u[] = $user['id'];

}
$update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `emailed` = 1 WHERE `id` = ?");
$update->bind_param('i', &$i);
$mysqli->autocommit(false);
foreach($u as $i)
    $update->execute();
$update->close();
$mysqli->commit();
```

Oh, almost forgot, most mysql storage engines are pretty stupid, make sure you use InnoDB, that one has has transaction support. Alternatively if you use a "stupid" storage engine you can still trick it into making a single transaction to update multiple rows if your users.id is int by doing

```
$update = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE users SET emailed=1 WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $u) . ')');
$update->execute();
$update->close();
```

after closing the `foreach($users as $user)` statement instead

Comment: Why though? Is there a difference from outside the loop at the end than in the loop? Sorry I don't see how it would  be any different performance-wise. @xception

Comment: check out the code I wrote, I perform a single transaction in which I update all of the rows that need updating, that's why it should be much faster, make a database copy, comment the mail calls not to spam the people and benchmark your version and mine on the exact same dataset in the copied database if you don't believe me, remember to reload the data after each test

Comment: I am using Inno because of foreign keys. I will test the answer and report back with my results in 10 mins. @xception

Comment: My version old code: 0.1238 seconds
New code (your answer): 0.0486 seconds

I am impressed it cutdown it by half. 

But I still need to fix the other cron job! @xception

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you, also let me know if you still experience issues at the 30 minute marks after changing both your scripts.

Comment: Haha @xception thanks for the help. It makes sense to me because you only prepare it once and just change the bound variable which is much faster. However I am stumped on how to make my other cron job faster as it uses HTTP requests then waits on the response then updates accordingly so I don't think I can do a transaction as it will be mixed results...

Comment: make 2 arrays, one with $info->data and the other one with the $token you use in case of error... and at the end turn autocommit off and call updateUser as many times as you need, than do the other transaction and call commit at the end, check updateUser function not to have a commit() call inside though, additionally you could cache the prepared statement used by updateUser as well

Comment: Oh, just realized, you probably have all kinds of other stuff happening in updateuser, just store in an array the changes you have to make after updateUser call instead... pull the sql out of the function and leave the rest

Comment: If it still takes too much time after these updates you probably do something very nasty (read slow) inside functions.php and you should post some of that as well for improvements probably in the updateUser function or some other function called by it.

Comment: The updateuser function is just three lines of php that is just a prepare bind_param and then execute. I can move it into the other file. @hakra

Comment: that's great :) let me know how it goes and vote my answer up if this actually helps, I'm trying to build up some reputation but it's going very very slowly

Answer (score -5):

Write more efficient scripts or get better hardware.

EDIT:

In terms of the mass email sending, you could add a timeout to your script so that it is not doing all the emails as quickly as possible. This would reduce load on the CPU but make your script take longer.

For instance:

```
for(all emails)
{
   //send email
   sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. At most it's a bad comment.

Comment: @MarcB admittedly a bit snarky, but without more information these are the only available answers. If he posts code I would be happy to try and help out with making the scripts more efficient.

Comment: Then put it up as a comment. Once you get the information, THEN write an answer